# How can I configure Vim to work with bitcoin core C++ source code and have Intellisense like functionality?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, c++, source-code

I use Vim for editing, I installed Conquer Of Completion (COC) plugin and now I can edit C++ projects with Vim taking advantage of syntax highlighting, autocompletion, inline error messages, etc. But when I try to open bitcoin source code files I get too many errors, like:

`Too many errors emitted, stopping now`
`'wallet/coinselection.h' file not found`
`Unknown type name 'OutputGroup'`
Etc.

Is there a best practice to work with the source code in Vim, or at least some general recommendations you can share?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, a build database, based on the project, had to be generated for [Clangd](https://clangd.llvm.org/installation.html) language server to do it's work. To do it, I used [Bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear), a tool that intercepts the build commands and generates a compilation database for clang tooling (compile_commands.json). I also made a video:
https://youtu.be/lC5USwFM6EQ (English),
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5tkgqzxic-Q (Spanish) explaining how I did the installation and configuration. I hope this helps other developers.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a problem with your plugin rather than Vim. Try disabling the plugin and see if you have the same issue. I have no problems opening and editing all Bitcoin Core source code files including `wallet/coinselection.h` with Vim.

I'm not a Vim guru by any means (hopefully someone who is will answer) but for recommendations on using Vim generally (not Bitcoin Core specific) [vimrc](https://github.com/amix/vimrc) is a popular Vim configuration and this [Changelog podcast](https://changelog.com/podcast/450) contained a number of tips for using Vim including links to the guests' dot files.

You'll want to make use of [vimdiff](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/625/how-do-i-use-vim-as-a-diff-tool) for reviewing pull requests. As Jon Atack says in this [doc](https://jonatack.github.io/articles/how-to-review-pull-requests-in-bitcoin-core):

> While the build and tests are running, begin reviewing each commit separately in your local environment using a diff tool like gitk, meld, meld for macOS, GNU ediff for Emacs, vimdiff or vim-diffconflicts for Vim, opendiff on macOS, or diffoscope

There is also a Vi/Vim [StackExchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thx, I'm very familiar with Vim configuration. I do can open Bitcoin source files, but I want autocopletion, goto definition and member list help. Do you use tab completion and goto definition when you edit bitcoin source files? Do you use any plugin?

Comment: @Bitcoin_1o1: I use ctags, cscope for goto definitions but personally I don't use autocompletion (excluding basic find and replace) or member list help. As I said I'm no Vim guru so there may be plugins for those. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vim-and-ctags-tips-and-tricks

Comment: You say "But when I try to open bitcoin source code files I get too many errors" in your question?

Comment: thanks, I managed to make it work, I'm going to make a video so other people who work with Vim can do the configuration. Best!

Comment: Cool, post the link here. I'll watch it :)